# Broadcast event for onConnected / onDisconnected event

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm looking for either broadcast receiver or service which catches whether the handheld device is recently started to connect and/or disconnect.

like `onPeerConnected`/ `onPeerDisconnected` but not deprecated and UI independent event.

Does such feature exist?

Comment: What do you mean by "UI independent event"?

Comment: @String any broadcast event. not activity initialized.

Comment: @String I've found onCapabilityChanged. But it is not fired properly. I will create a new question about it.

Comment: @String https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001358/oncapabilitychanged-is-not-fired-on-both-handheld-and-wearable this question

Comment: Since this [document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.NodeListener#onPeerConnected) told us that `onPeerConnected/ onPeerDisconnected` is deprecated, you may check out the  [Capability API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi) which enables an app to advertise a capability on a node and listen for its existence on other nodes. It Exposes an API to learn about capabilities provided by nodes on the Wear network.

Comment: @Vyacheslav since you opened a new question (45001358) about the Capability API, I've posted an answer over there instead.