# onCapabilityChanged is not fired on both handheld and wearable while disabling/enabling connections

Tags: android, wear-os

```
<service android:name=".SMessage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/send-message" android:scheme="wear" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


public class SMessage extends WearableListenerService {

@Override
        public void onCapabilityChanged(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
        super.onCapabilityChanged(capabilityInfo);
        _A.toast("onCapabilityChanged");
        Set<Node> connectedNodes = capabilityInfo.getNodes();
        pickBestNodeId(connectedNodes);
    }
}
```

this method is not fired `onCapabilityChanged` if I enable aircraft mode or disable bluetooth connection.

What have I missed?
`_A.toast` shows toast using Application class.

Sending messages works.!

Comment: You need to register for `Intent. ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED` IntentFilter with BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski nonetheless, this event interrupts the connection between the devices. So, it have to catch connection loosing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include an `android:path` element that identifies the (fully-qualified) capability you're listening for:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
    <data android:host="*" android:scheme="wear" 
          android:path="/com.mypackagename.my_capability_name"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

where `my_capability_name` is defined in the `wear.xml` of your app running on the other device:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>my_capability_name</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

as documented at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html#AdvertiseCapabilities.

A couple of caveats, however:

- Because your app will run **every** time the devices dis/connect, you could see significant battery drain as a result.
- As with all other manifest-declared broadcast receivers, this will stop working in Android O: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#broadcasts